# ios11 beta and ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ios11, xcode9

I have an Ionic 2 application which is working perfectly with my XCode 8 and ios 10. 
I'm trying the same app with the xcode 9 beta and ios11, but I can't compile the project. 
I've tried several things like :

- Compiling with : ionic cordova build ios ---> The prepare works, but it blocks at the build instruction (it never ends)
- Compiling directly with Xcode ---> The compilation process blocks at the "compiling asset catalog" step, it never ends as well.

I have a project which compile perfectly with xcode8, but if I open the same project with xcode 9 i have the same problem (it blocks on compiling asset catalog).

What could be the problem ? (I saw the webview plugin has some problems but I don't use it).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works with the GM version !